# Select input field in injected div doesn't work on parse.com in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, colorbox

We have a Firefox extension that injects a `div` into the page. The `div` has a Z index of 2.14748e+9 (i.e. the highest allowed value). One site (parse.com) displays a modal Login dialog by putting a grey overlay over the whole page (absolute positioned).

Despite the fact that the z index of the overlay is lower (and so the `div` is not greyed out), the `select` field in the `div` does not open when clicked. If I right click on the field then the context menu appears, and after that it can be opened with a click as expected. So this looks to be some kind of focus issue.

All of this works fine in Chrome.

**Update**: Even when I delete the overlay `div` the input fields in the injected `div` fail to get keystrokes, so it looks like the modal dialog is capturing the events.

Comment: What's the page structure, are both the colorbox and this `div` being added at the top level (meaning: as children of the `body` tag)? If not, then maybe the lower Z index of the `div`'s parent node plays a role here.

Comment: Yes they are both direct children on the `body`. Actually the overlay used by the modal dialog looks have the class `ui-widget-overlay`. Upon further examination I don't think the colorbox is related. In fact, even the modal overlay doesn't seem to be related since the injected `div` fails to get keystrokes even if I delete the overlay in the Inspector. I guess their must be some JavaScript involved and I'm examining that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the z-index of the injected `div` was causing the problem. Any value of 9999995 or greater (no really!) prevents it from gaining focus. Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a bug to me, so I filed it in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=988265).

Comment: +1 thanks for sharing this very interesting. I never use such large numbers but this really helps out.

Comment: Im watching you on Bugzilla man, you are really helping out by sticking with it by delievering testcase etc. Thanks man

Comment: And props to you on finding the number 9999995 thats crazy work man